# Why is は here used but not が？

Tags: grammar

I have this sentence from a friend:

> あなたが選ぶ女の子の趣味は格別です。

Meaning: Your taste in women is exceptional.

My guess is that the direct translation would be:

> Speaking of the taste of choosing women, you are exceptional.

I would have thought that the は and が would be reversed since I was taught to use が with adjectives. I might have said something like this:

> あなたは選ぶ女の子の趣味が格別です。

but perhaps for this sentence, the meaning is more:

> Speaking of you, the taste of choosing women is exceptional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> あなたが選ぶ女の子の趣味は格別です。
>   Speaking of the taste of choosing women, you are exceptional.

You don't seem to be parsing it correctly, I'm afraid. あなたが選ぶ is a relative clause modifying 女の子.

> （あなたが選ぶ）女の子の趣味は格別です。

Its direct translation would be like:

> The taste of girls (that you choose) is exceptional.

You can also say it as:

> あなた**の**選ぶ女の子の趣味は格別です。

Comment: Ah thank you. Your explanation was helpful.